# I'm trying to override CSS Classes of 'react-carousel-component' but in different parts of the website

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I'm currently using **react-responsive-carousel** to make a slider on this website: [www.bosquo.pl](https://www.bosquo.pl) the problem is that the carousel is being used in different parts of the website and depending on the part I want to override in different ways. E.g in the code side

I already tried to override in a CSS stylesheet but the change propagates to all of the components.

I would like to have one section using the Carousel with one style and another section with another style.

Comment: By override, do you mean you tried `!important`?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Id for the parent of (spacific Items or your class) in your Html code and then you are abel to adress your css selector to your class usign parentID. (if you mean override, then as 'TheUnknow' said, you can use '!important' after your Css values.

ex. of your Html Code:

```
<div id='parent'>
<div class='items'></div>
<div class='items'></div>
<div class='items'></div>
</div>
```

ex. of your Css:

```
#parent items {
width:20px !important)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap your carousel component in to `div` with specific class. And use that class to target carousel.

Your jsx code:

```js
const TwoCarousel = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="carousel1">
                <CarouselComponent />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel2">
                <CarouselComponent />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And then you scss code:

```
.carousel1 {
  .slider-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
  }
}
.carousel2 {
  .slider-wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }  
}
```

Comment: i tried as you suggested but it didnt work, instead did it like this 
.carousel>div>div>ul>li then i override  its properties using !important.
i know its not the best method to do it but its was my only choice :/